# Direct Digital Synthesis - What is Phase Truncation?

Tags: c++, matlab, arduino, signal-processing

I'm developing a Direct Digital Synthesis (DDS) waveform generator on the Arduino Due in C/C++.  But I'm first implementing an example in Matlab to make sure I understand the main components, which are: the Phase or Angle Accumulator (N-bits), the Lookup table (P-bits), and the Digital-to-Analog converter (12-bits).  I understand these basic elements.

The Lookup table size will match the DAC resolution, so P=12.  The Accumulator will be at least 16-bits long (N=16).  So phase truncation must occur here.  Therein lies my confusion and my question.  How does this truncation work?  What does it mean to take the P significant bits of N?

Comment: This question belongs on [Signal Processing SE](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Imagine you had your PA represented in floating point. You can only use the (truncated) integer part of that floating point number as an index, but you still accumulate with full floating point precision to minimize error.

Answer (score 1):

In general, if you have *N bit long* value, one possible value, let say **(in binary, i.e. epxressed using 2 bits (1's and 0's), where each bit, depending on its position represents a power of 2)** is:
1000 1111 0000 1010
 The most significant bits are the ones counting from left to right, i.e.: the four most significant bits in the example are: 1000. So, truncating by taking the P significant bits means that you count till P from left to right and what is left is ignored.
 **In decimal representation, i.e. expressed using 10 numbers (0,1,..,8,9)**, this will be analogous to: if your values is : 110124 and you take only P=3  significant numbers, you will remain with: 110000, i.e. the 3 least significant numbers (124) are not regarded, thereby loosing some detail.

Comment: In C: `index = pac >> (N-P);` or, with 0.5-rouding: `index = ((pac >> (N-P-1)) + 1) >> 1;`

Comment: Answer on "the most significant bits" understood.  Thanks for the analogy.  In the context of an Arduino C++ program looping at a sample rate of Fs, how is the truncation dealt with?  As the N-bit Phase Accumulator grows to the size 2^N (corresponding to angle 2*pi), how is the P-bit Lookup table evaluated if P is less than N?  Is it simply a matter of skipping?  To Hanno Binder, is that what your code indicates?

Answer (score 1):

This binary math and bitwise manipulation is new to me, but I'm beginning to understand.  I implemented a Direct Digital Synthesis (DDS) example in Matlab.  Code below for others.  May also run on Octave.

```
% INPUT PARAMETERS
%-----------------------
fs    = 2^14;   % Clock Sample Rate (hz)
NT    = 1e4;    % Total Samples for example 
foutd = 80;     % Desired Output Freq. (hz)
N     = 16;     % Accumulator resolution (bits)
P     = 12;     % Lookup Table resolution (bits)


% FREQUENCY TUNING WORD
%------------------------------
FTWf = foutd/fs*2^N;          % float
FTW  = round(foutd/fs*2^N);   % actual integer term for accumulator
fout = FTW*fs/2^N;            % actual output frequency


% SINE WAVE LOOKUP TABLE
%---------------------------
x = [0:2^P-1]';
y = sin(x*2*pi / (2^P-1) );


% INITIALIZE
%--------------------------
dt    = 1/fs;                % Time Step (sec)
t     = [0:dt:dt*(NT-1)]';   % Time Vector
phase = zeros(NT,1);         % Save phase vs. time
wave  = zeros(NT,1);         % Save wave amplitude vs. time


% SAMPLE THROUGH TIME
%-----------------------
pa = 0;   % Phase accumulator

for ii=1:length(t)

    % ACCUMULATE PHASE
    pa = pa + FTW;

    % ROLLOVER PHASE
    if pa > 2^N
        pa = 1;
    end 

    % PHASE TRUNCATION
    indx = ceil(pa * 2^(P-N));

    % LOOKUP
    phase(ii) = pa;
    wave(ii)  = y( indx );

end

figure;
subplot(211),  plot(t, phase); grid on;
subplot(212),  plot(t, wave);  grid on; hold on
               plot(t,sin(foutd*2*pi*t), 'r-.');
```

My next step is to implement this on the ArduinoDue.  This algorithm will be the basis of the ISR interrupt function.  I will definitely use binary operators to speed up the division (i.e., "Phase Truncation").

After that, I need to figure out how to handle non-integer frequency inputs.